# How to override with app language over device language for dynamic data

Tags: android, locale, miui

My app supports 2 languages. For the strings provided res/values folder, the result is as expected when app language is changed. But on some devices like Xiaomi, One Plus devices, numbers which are dynamic data is shown in device language and not in selected app language.

Comment: You can check [change-app-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46813019/change-app-language/46814872#46814872) .

Answer (score 0):

Not depend on your support language. You have to create a default language `string.xml` in the resource folder. Dynamic data is shown in device language and not in selected app language should be the default language.